# Updating radio button value before click event executes

Tags: angular

I have an issue where click events on my radio buttons that set or clear specific validators are doing so before the value actually changes.

If the Yes radio button is clicked, I'd like to toggle the validators for the additional field it shows.  If not, I'd like to clear the validators of the additional field it hides.  It shows and hides the field properly via *ngIf, but the validator method executes before the value changes.  So the first time the value is undefined, then each time after it shows the value before change.

Example below.
Template snippet.

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="infraRadio" [value]="1" (click)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.infraRadio'),[changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.newInfrastructure')])">Yes
<input type="radio" formControlName="infraRadio" [value]="0" (click)="radioSetValidator(changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.infraRadio'),[changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.newInfrastructure')])">No


<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" formControlName="newInfrastructure" style="width:100%"
*ngIf="changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.infraRadio').value=='1'"> </textarea>
```

Method in component class:

```
radioSetValidator(c: FormControl, d: [FormControl]) {
if (+c.value === 1) {
  d.forEach(element => {
    element.setValidators(Validators.required);
  });

} else {
  d.forEach(element => {
    element.clearValidators();
  });
}
```

}

I'm still trying to wrap my head around angular as a whole, so the answer here may be obvious.  Almost all other examples of this kind of behaviour that I've seen while trying to do my research seem to involve ngModel and onModelChange, but that doesn't seem to apply to me or work.  Can someone help me discern what needs to be changes for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `(change)` event binding instead of click.

Other possibility would be to pass the value to the function as another parameter:

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="infraRadio" [value]="1" (click)="radioSetValidator(1, changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.infraRadio'),[changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.newInfrastructure')])">Yes
<input type="radio" formControlName="infraRadio" [value]="0" (click)="radioSetValidator(0, changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.infraRadio'),[changeForm.get('changeAssessmentFG.newInfrastructure')])">No

radioSetValidator(value: number, c: FormControl, d: [FormControl]) {
  if (value === 1) {
    d.forEach(element => {
      element.setValidators(Validators.required);
    });

  } else {
    d.forEach(element => {
      element.clearValidators();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, passing the value is absolutely the infinitely more simple approach.  Thank you so much.